# Duemilanove serial TX/RX: which is what?

Tags: serial, arduino-duemilanove

I want to use the GSM shield. For my project, I will hook it up directly to pins `0` and `1` (TX/RX). Will it work right away? Do I have to know which is TX and which RX and declare it?

I will not be using SoftwareSerial.

Answer (score 2):

> I will not be using SoftwareSerial

That means you'll use the standard `Serial()` library.

> Do I have to[...] declare it?

Not if you use the standard `Serial.begin()` instruction. The Duemilanove uses pins 0/1 automatically for TX/RX

> Do I have to know which is TX and which RX?

Kinda... you have to know which one is which so you wire it correctly. The TX of the board should go to the RX of the GSM shield, and vice versa. Pin 0 is RX and 1 is TX.